# How to tell whether HTML elements are block or inline

Tags: html, dom

Actually I don't know what keyword(s) to google. :)

I want to know, which HTML elements are display:block or display:inline by default. Let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a W3C document for you: [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)

Comment: The elements which aren't explicitly listed in that CSS are `display:inline` (which is the default value for the `display` property)

Comment: there is no `span` or span is not valid in HTML 4?

Answer (score 1):

They're all `display:inline` except for the ones which are defined otherwise in the [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html).

Comment: I think I've seen `display:block` as default in the latest Chrome.

Comment: so should declare `div {display:block;}` in css?

Comment: @wow `div` is already `display:block` in the [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html); but other elements like `<strong>` for which the `display` property isn't defined in the Default style sheet for HTML 4, are assigned the default/initial value for `display` [which is defined as `inline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display).